# SQL Server 'CONTAINS' slower than 'LIKE' with multiple expressions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

This takes about a minute:

```
SELECT * 
FROM someBigTable 
WHERE someColumn LIKE '%foo bar%' 
OR someColumn LIKE '%hey macarena%'
```

This takes 4-6 minutes:

```
SELECT * 
FROM someBigTable 
WHERE CONTAINS(someColumn, '"foo bar" OR "hey macarena"')
```

I repeated each query several times to make sure it wasn't just a fluke.

`someColumn` is indexed.

This happens with some pairs of expressions (say, "foo bar" and "hey macarena") but not with others. But shouldn't 'CONTAINS' always be faster than 'LIKE'? What could be causing 'CONTAINS' to be slower than 'LIKE' in some cases?

(Windows Server 2012, SQL Server 2012)

**EDIT**:

Execution plan of the first query:

[image]

Execution plan of the second query:

[image]

**EDIT 2: execution plans of a "normal" case ('CONTAINS' faster than 'LIKE')**

Execution plan of the first query (~59 seconds):

[image]

Execution plan of the second query (~4 seconds):

[image]

Comment: those queries aren't equivalent. The first can return results like "mafoo bartender"

Comment: @Lamack I know, but shouldn't that make 'LIKE' even slower, since it returns more results?

Comment: Do you have a full text index on the column in question? `CONTAINS` can only use a full text index, I'm pretty sure.

Comment: Is there a clustered index on the table?  If so, is there significant fragmentation within the index?  Have statistics on the table been updated recently?  When was the last time you performed a `REORGANIZE` on the Full Text Catalog?

Comment: @Andrew Yes, there is.

Comment: @DMason Yes, there is a clustered index. I'll have to check the rest.

Comment: @swasheck I'll edit the question to add the execution plans of a "normal" case (CONTAINS faster than LIKE).

Comment: Regarding Andrew's observation, you should check to see whether any stoplists/stopwords are defined, as they will affect which keywords in a fulltext query may be matched from the index. See: Configure and Manage Stopwords and Stoplists for Full-Text Search https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142551.aspx and CREATE FULLTEXT STOPLIST (Transact-SQL) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280405.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning more results isn't a real indication for tuning a query. It does affect networking and such, but not the actual efficiency.  What matters more is how much data is scanned to retrieve the data, which indexes are utilized, and how (ordered=true/false). As well as other actions the optimizer takes.

In your example, the two procedures aren't equal. Without the '*' indicator, the Contain() here acts as a full text search and as such is using a specific full-text index.
The like '%%' just does a full-table-scan on the smallest index that contains the column in the where clause, and the look-up is for the columns not in that index.

So in this case, it greatly depends on how the indexes are declared.